# Why does isset nullify form validation in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Why does the following code nullify form validation in CodeIgniter?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Can anybody advise how do I overcome that?

If I comment out by // the form validation works OK but I need the isset for the other coding to work.

REPLY

Thanks DFriend, I did have the "name" attribute in the view page as follows. I noted your use of single quotes as opposed to my double quotes but changing those made no difference.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
```

This is the coding in the Controller;

```
public function index()
{
    $error = 0;
    $realname = "";
    $username = "";
    $word = "";

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'file'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $config = array(
            array('field' => 'rname', 'label' => 'RealName', 'rules' => 'required',
                'errors' => array('required' => 'Provide%s')),
            array('field' => 'uname', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'required',
                'errors' => array('required' => 'Provide%s')),
            array('field' => 'word', 'label' => 'Word', 'rules' => 'required', 'errors' => array(
                    'required' => 'Provide%s')));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('names');
        }

    $realname = $this->input->post('rname');
    $username = $this->input->post('uname');
    $word = $this->input->post('word');

    if( ! file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file1/$realname")) exit("$realname DoesNotExist");
    if( ! file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file2/$realname/$username")) exit("$username DoesNotExist");
    if( ! file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file3/$realname/$word")) exit("$word DoesNotExist");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) redirect(BASE_URL.'home');

 }
```

If I comment out by //if(isset.. the form validation works OK but I need the "isset" for the other coding to work.

There are two functions in the coding above, one ensures the text boxes are filled in and not left empty (form validation), and the other ensures the text boxes are filled in correctly (if !file_exits). Both functions work good individually but they wont work together.

Answer (score 0):

From jreklund

```
public function index()
{
$error = 0;
$realname = "";
$username = "";
$word = "";

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','file'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$config = array(
    array('field' => 'rname', 'label' => 'RealName', 'rules' => 'required', 'errors' => array( 'required' => 'Provide%s')),
    array('field' => 'uname', 'label' => 'Username', 'rules' => 'required', 'errors' => array( 'required' => 'Provide%s')),
    array('field' => 'word', 'label' => 'Word', 'rules' => 'required', 'errors' => array( 'required' => 'Provide%s'))
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('names');
}
else
{

    $realname = $this->input->post('rname');
    $username = $this->input->post('uname');
    $word = $this->input->post('word');

    if(!file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file1/$realname")) exit ("$realname DoesNotExist");
    if(!file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file2/$realname/$username")) exit ("$username DoesNotExist");
    if(!file_exists("C:xampp/htdocs/file3/$realname/$word")) exit ("$word DoesNotExist");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) redirect(BASE_URL.'home');
    }
}
```